# What is the reason for central uplift of a complex crater?

Tags: meteors

For a central uplift there must be a rebounding effect in the crater. What causes this effect? Does melting occur on crater impact?

Comment: [Read chapter 3](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/publications/books/CB-954/chapter3.pdf)

Comment: This might be better for space.SE. @Farcher: The link is to a pdf of a chapter of a book. What book is it and who's the author?

Comment: The relevant part of the pdf link supplied by Farcher seems to be section 3.2.2, and the answer seems to be that nobody knows for sure.

Comment: @BenCrowell Sorry, I was in a hurry. The book is [Traces of Catastrophe by Bevan M French](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/publications/books/CB-954/CB-954.pdf) available from the [Lunar and Planetary Institute](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/publications/books/) website.